# Can you please explain how BAT54C (D4A,D4B,D4A,D5B,D7,BAT54A) works in this circuit?

Tags: power-supply

From right to left:

1. DC power supply of 9 V -0.8 A in fig (J5,J6)
2. small signal schottkey diode BAT54C (D5A,D5B), D5A only pins 1 and 3 are used, for D5B pin 2 and 3 are used
3. there is a capacitor c26
4. Voltage regulator HT7150
5. diode D4A and D4B (BAT54C)
6. diode D7 and BAT54A/SOT

Can you please tell me the working how those diode works and its output? I am talking about all diodes in the circuit. Also I am confused with the Voltage regulator - what is its value?

> [image]

Comment: For image of circuit please click on blue writing up saying from right to left

Answer (score 5):

D4A and D4B allow switching between power supplied by the regulator (u5) and from an external supply connected at J4. Whichever supply provides a higher voltage will power the rest of the circuit.

D5A and D5B protect against reverse connection of the external supply at J6 or J5. I suspect they are doubled-up only because BAT54C is a dual part and the designer did not want to leave one device floating. And did not want to use an alternate PN in order to gain higher purchasing volumes and lower costs for the BAT54C.

Comment: i also want to know what is the output of BAT54A/SOT and D7 (BAT54A)  and what is Vref

Comment: I think D7 is a dual diode part, with both devices shown in the same symbol. The voltage on the cathodes would be Vreg-0.7 V or so, assuming there's no other power source connected to those nets. I don't see any Vref in your diagram, so I can't say anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

All these diodes are packaged as common anode on pin3 and pins 1 and 2 are the cathodes of 2 diodes. I makes no difference whether you use pin 1 or 2 for any situation, in the D5A/B case they are in parallel anyway.

The HT7150 is a 5v Regulator and C25 / C26 are for stability to prevent any oscillation.

This whole circuit seems very odd. It looks like the main objective is to provide 6v volts out from a 6 volt battery. The diodes are schottkey because they have lower forward voltage drop than "normal" diodes. The 2x 9v battery and regulator seems to be a backup to prevent  the output falling below 5v if the main battery dies or is replaced, i.e backup. the Vreg output will be the greater of them . D4A/B is the prevent either supply line feeding the other so the Regulator wont be trying to charge the dead 6v battery and the 6volt battery wont be reverse biasing the regulator.

D7 is the reverse  of the others being common cathode but we don't know where this feeds to so can't say much about it.

Also we don't know the size of any battery so can only speculate on some of what is happening.

Comment: I forgot to say D7 is the reverse of the others i.e. common Cathode but since we don't know where this feeds to it is unclear why it used.

Comment: D7 is feeding to another voltage regulator HT7133

Answer (score -1):

If i had to guess, I would say it is included in the circuit to prevent reverse-polarity voltage being applied to C26 and U5. The diode should prevent any problems/issues if the voltage source (J6) is connected backwards.

EDIT:

perhaps the next question is, "Why are there two of them?"

I don't know the answer to that.

EDIT2:

The circuit elements that you list do not occur from right to left.

If you want to know how the voltage regulator works, google the datasheet.

Comment: can u please explain me what happen when two diodes like say D5A and D5B are connected with pin 1and 3 for D5A and Pin 2 and 3 of D5B. u can refer circuit